# How to get around "Can't convert nil into String (TypeError)" when reading a csv file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I am working on a program that will eventually compare two .csv files and print out any variances between the two. However, at the moment I can't get past a "can't convert nil into String (TypeError)" when reading one of the files.

Here is a sample line from the problematic csv file:

```
11/13/15,11:31:00,ABCD,4000150097,1321126281700ABCDEF,WR00002440,,,4001,1392,AI,INTERNAL RETURN,INBOUND,,ABCDEF
```

And here is my code so far:

```
require 'csv'
class CSVReportCompare

  def initialize(filename_data, filename_compare)
    puts "setting filename_data=", filename_data
    puts "setting compare=", filename_compare
    @filename_data = filename_data
    @filenam_compare = filename_compare
  end

  def printData
    @data = CSV.read(@filename_data)
    puts @data.inspect
  end

  def printCompareData
    @compareData = CSV.read(@filename_compare)
    puts @compareData.inspect
  end

  def compareData

  end

end

c1 = CSVReportCompare.new("data.csv", "compare_data.csv")
c1.printData
c1.printCompareData
```

Anyways, is there a way to get around the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `initialize` method:

```
@filenam_compare = filename_compare
#-------^ missing "e"
```

So you're setting the wrong instance variable. Instance variables are created when they're first used and initialized to `nil` so later, when you try to access `@filename_compare`, the instance variable with the *correct* name is created and has a value of `nil`.

Comment: Wow, glad it was my fault and not a problem with the csv file... thank you!

Comment: @sean: If you had warnings on, it would have warned you about `@filename_compare` being uninitialized.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh how I wish warnings were enabled by default. Do we really have to learn this exact same lesson with every single language?

Comment: @muistooshort: Why not propose it for Ruby 2.0?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I will make sure to run my scripts with warnings on. Is there a way to have Ruby always run scripts with warnings (instead of calling scripts with `ruby -w script.rb`? I've been searching around and haven't come up with a way to do this.