# How can I run all Ruby scripts with warnings?

Tags: ruby, warnings, environment-variables

How can I always run Ruby scripts with warnings turned on by default, by modifying my Unix or Windows environment variables?

Ideally this should work even when I'm running a script indirectly such as through Rake, not just when I'm running it directly.

Based on a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140785/how-to-get-around-cant-convert-nil-into-string-typeerror-when-reading-a-csv/8140827#8140827).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `RUBYOPT` environment variable defines default options like warnings, etc.

**Unix/OS X/etc:**

```
export RUBYOPT=-w
```

You can put this in your startup script in Unix so it's set for new shells.

**Windows:**

```
set RUBYOPT=-w
```

Use the system properties dialog to set it for new shells/command windows.