# How to decide whether an optional argument was given or not in a ruby method

Tags: ruby, optional-parameters

I have a method with an optional argument. How can I decide whether the Argument was given or not?

I came up with the following solutions. I am asking this question since I am not entirely satisfied with any of them. Exists there a better one?

## `nil` as default value

```
def m(a= nil)
    if a.nil?
        ...
    end
end
```

The drawback with this one is, that it cannot be decided whether no argument or `nil` was given.

## custom `NoArgument` as default value

```
class NoArgument
end

def m(a= NoArgument.new)
    if NoArgument === a
        ...
    end
end
```

Whether `nil` was given can be decided, but the same problem exists for instances of `NoArgument`.

## Evaluating the size of an ellipsis

```
def m(*a)
    raise ArgumentError if m.size > 1
    if m.size == 1
        ...
    end
end
```

In this variant it can be always decided whether the optional argument was given.
However the `Proc#arity` of this method has changed from 1 to -1 (not true, see the comment). It still has the disadvantage of beeing worse to document and needing to manually raise the ArgumentError.

Comment: The `arity` of all your methods is `-1`. The last solution's only drawback is that you have to manually check that no more than one argument is given and documentation is needed to know what are the arguments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jorg W Mittag has the [following code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422328/38765) that can do what you want:

```
def foo(bar = (bar_set = true; :baz))
  if bar_set
    # optional argument was supplied
  end
end
```

Comment: What would be a use case for this?

Comment: @AndrewF: That question would be better answered by johannes or Jorg W Mittag.

Comment: There are some methods in the core library which behave differently depending on the number of arguments supplied. In effect, they simulate argument-based dispatch. In most Ruby implementations, those methods are implemented in C, C++, Java, C# etc. and they have privileged access to Ruby internals, so they *can* actually simply check the number of arguments. But, if you want to write a compatible method in Ruby, you have to resort to tricks like this.

Comment: I think this works the other way around. Your `bar_set` variable is only set when Ruby has to work out the default value for the param, so it's actually set to `true` when `bar` is not given. Perhaps the variable should be named `bar_omitted`?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
NO_ARGUMENT = Object.new

def m(a = NO_ARGUMENT)
    if a.equal?(NO_ARGUMENT)
        #no argument given
    end
end
```

Comment: This is the method employed by Rubinius, for example.

Comment: The only disadvantage with this approach is that the method may decide to pass `NO_ARGUMENT` as an argument to another method using this idiom.