# Optional argument syntax

Tags: ruby, optional-arguments

I found this code under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421658/why-does-ruby-not-treat-this-as-a-syntax-error/8422328#8422328), which checks if any argument is passed to a method:

```
def foo(bar = (bar_set = true; :baz))
  if bar_set
    # optional argument was supplied
  end
end
```

What is the purpose of the `; :baz` in this default value, and in what case would I use it?

Comment: Write code to print `bar` (and perhaps also `bar_set`) and then call `foo` first with zero arguments and then with one.

Comment: Very instructive, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that `= (bar_set = true; :baz)` will be evaluated only if a value is not passed to the `bar` parameter.

In Ruby, the return value of multiple consecutive expressions is the value of the last expression. Hence `= (bar_set = true; :baz)` assigns the value `true` to `bar_set`, and then sets `:baz` as the value for `bar` (because the code in the parentheses will evaluate to `:baz`, it being the last expression).

If a parameter was passed, `bar_set` will be `nil` and the value of `bar` would be whatever was given.

Comment: This is needed because whatever value you use as the default can also be passed by the caller, so it is impossible to know by looking at the value whether or not an argument was passed. But a method might want to know that. E.g., if you have a custom collection which allows very fast folding, you might want to override `Enumerable#inject`, but its contract is pretty complex, it basically has 4 "overloads". This is not a problem for YARV, JRuby and co, because they implement it in C or Java and thus have privileged access to the VM, but in Ruby, you need tricks like this.

Comment: :-D I just noticed that the answer which inspired this question is mine :-D