# Facter - How to check if directory exists

Tags: puppet, facter

I'm trying to check if direcotory exists. I created subdir 'lib/facter' in my module directory and put file 'mycheck.rb' in it.

```
Facter.add(:mycheck) do
 setcode do
  if Dir.exist? ('/mydir1')
   'one'
  elseif Dir.exist? ('/mydir2')
   'two'
  else
   'default'
  end
 end
end
```

Even if both directories 'mydir1' and 'mydir2' exists I always got 'default' value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a syntax issue. You need `elsif` and not `elseif`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421658/why-is-this-not-a-syntax-error for why Ruby returns default each time due to the malformed syntax in your fact.

Comment: Yeah, I found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer. It should be 'elsif' not 'elseif'. Now it works great.